# Asp.net pass value from txtbox to an another page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This the end of my code

```
 ...
 If lblErrMsg.Text = "" Then

     Response.Redirect("UserPage.aspx")
    End If
```

I want to pass the value of txtUser(I create It in the current  page...)  to the UserPage.aspx.

Thank's for helping me ...

This is in VB.net not in c# Please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**C# Version**

1) Use querystring

```
Response.Redirect("user.aspx?val="+txtBox.Text);
```

and in userp.aspx.cs,

```
string strVal=Request.QueryString["val"];
```

2)Use Session

Setting session in first page before redirecting

```
Session["val]=txtBox.Text;
Response.Redirect("user.aspx");
```

and in user.aspx.cs

```
  String strVal=(string) Session["val"];
```

**EDIT :VB.NET VERSION**

1) Use Querystring

```
Response.Redirect("user.aspx?val=" + txtBox.Text)
```

and in user.aspx.vb

```
Dim strVal As String = Request.QueryString("val")
```

2)Use Session

Setting Session in firstpage

```
Session("val")=txtBox.Text
Response.Redirect("user.aspx")
```

and in user.aspx.vb.

```
Dim strVal As String = DirectCast(Session("val"), String)
```

Comment: This is in c# please i want it in Vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it in the query string, like this:

```
Response.Redirect("UserPage.aspx?user=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtUser.Text));
```

And then retrieve it via:

```
string user = Request.QueryString["user"];
```

If you're worried about users messing with a query string (be sure to validate it), you could also store a [Session variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) before doing the redirect.

Comment: I add  the Response.Redirect before the  Response.Redirect("UserPage.aspx") and in the page load of UserPage.aspx I wrote string user = Request.QueryString["user"]; and it recognize get me error... Your code is not in c#?

Answer (score 0):

warning: this is a gross but easy solution

```
Session("myTextbox")= txtUser.Text
```

this will persist the value so on the page_load of the next page you can say

```
txtUser.Text=Session("myTextBox")
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you passing form page to page?  Is it a list of things.  You could have an object with different properties and could then pass it through a session.  If you have multiple pages I would suggest doing this if you could end up reusing it else where.  Passing it through the url, you would then need to validate it, because if someone types the url with the correct information or something that is being directly input into a database they could cause problems and/or unexpected results.